# Idiomatic clojure map lookup by keyword

Tags: clojure

Say I have a clojure map that uses keywords as its keys:

```
(def my-car {:color "candy-apple red" :horsepower 450})
```

I know that I can look up the value associated with the keyword by either using the keyword or the map as a function and the other as its argument:

```
(my-car :color)
; => "candy-apple red"
(:color my-car)
; => "candy-apple red"
```

I realize that both forms can come in handy for certain situations, but is one of them considered more idiomatic for straightforward usage like shown above?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`(:color my-car)` is fairly standard. There are a few reasons for this, and I won't go into all of them. But here's an example.

Because `:color` is a constant, and `my-car` is not, hotspot can completely inline the dynamic dispatch of `color.invoke(m)`, which it can't do with `m.invoke(color)` (in some java pseudo-code).

That gets even better if `my-car` happens to sometimes be a record with a `color` field instead of a plain map: the clojure compiler can emit code to check "hey, if `my-car` is an instance of CarType, then just return `my-car.color`; otherwise do all the complicated, slow, hashmap lookup."

Comment: For me, the most compelling reason: (:color nil) returns nil, whereas (nil :color) throws an Exception.

Comment: @user100464 But the same argument could be made about the other form!  If you're dynamically accessing keys, `({:color "red"} nil)` returns `nil` while `(nil {:color "red"})` throws an exception.

Comment: Based on my testing results, at REPL, `(get hash-map key)` is the fastest, `(hash-map key)` the second, and `(key hash-map)` is the slowest among these three forms. The results are quite consistent.

Answer (score 25):

From the [library coding standards](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards):

> - Use keyword-first syntax to access properties on objects:
>
>   ```
>   (:property object-like-map)
>   ```
> - Use collection-first syntax to extract values from a collection (or use get if the collection might be nil).
>
>   ```
>   (collection-like-map key)
>   (get collection-like-map key)
>   ```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between an "object-like map" and a "collection-like map"?

Comment: @Peeja I'm not 100% sure of this, but I interpreted an "object like map" as a map with predefined keys and their properties such as having `{:first first, :last last, :age age }` being a Person object, while having a map of people's names that were read from a database as keys and their information as values as an example of a "collection like map". Also note that names that were read from a database are more likely to be strings than keywords, therefore precluding using the first lookup form anyway.

Answer (score 9):

I put together a list of arguments for and against the two forms.  (**Edit:** Added third option - `(get map :key)` which is my new favorite despite being a little bit more verbose)

## Arguments for (:key map)

1) Requested in coding standards

http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards

2) Still works when map is nil

```
> (:a nil)
  nil
> (nil :a)
  ERROR: can't call nil
```

---counterargument--- if key may be nil, other forms are better

```
> ({:a "b"} nil)
  nil
> (nil {:a "b"})
  ERROR: can't call nil
```

3) Works better for threading and mapping over collections of objects

```
(-> my-map
  :alpha
  fn-on-alpha
  :beta
  fn-on-beta
  :gamma

> (def map-collection '({:key "values"} {:key "in"} {:key "collection"}))
> (map :key map-collection)
  ("values" "in" "collection")
```

---counterargument--- the code structure of threading is different than
usual so different idiomatic tendencies could be applied for map access
when needed

4) Potential optimization benefit? (needs verification)

## Arguments for (map :key)

1) Does not throw error when key is non-keyword or nil

```
> ({:a "b"} nil)
  nil
> (nil {:a "b"})
  ERROR: can't call nil
> ({"a" "b"} "a")
  "b"
> ("a" {"a" "b"})
  ERROR: string cannot be cast to IFn
```

2) Consistency with list access in Clojure

```
> ([:a :b :c] 1)
  :b
> (1 [:a :b :c])
  ERROR: long cannot be cast to IFn
```

3) Similarity to other forms of object access

```
java>         my_obj  .alpha  .beta  .gamma  .delta
clj >     ((((my-map  :alpha) :beta) :gamma) :delta)
clj > (get-in my-map [:alpha  :beta  :gamma  :delta])
cljs> (aget   js-obj  "alpha" "beta" "gamma" "delta")
```

4) Alignment when accessesing multiple keys from the same map (separate lines)

```
> (my-func
    (my-map :un)
    (my-map :deux)
    (my-map :trois)
    (my-map :quatre)
    (my-map :cinq))
> (my-func
    (:un my-map)
    (:deux my-map)
    (:trois my-map)
    (:quatre my-map)
    (:cinq my-map))
```

---counterargument--- alignment worse when accessing same key from multiple maps

```
> (my-func
    (:key map-un)
    (:key map-deux)
    (:key map-trois)
    (:key map-quatre)
    (:key map-cinq)
> (my-func
    (map-un :key)
    (map-deux :key)
    (map-trois :key)
    (map-quatre :key)
    (map-cinq :key)
```

## Arguments for (get map :key)

1) NEVER causes error if arg1 is map/vector/nil and arg2 is key/index/nil

```
> (get nil :a)
  nil
> (get nil nil)
  nil
> (get {:a "b"} nil)
  nil
> (get {:a "b"} :q)
  nil
> (get [:a :b :c] nil)
  nil
> (get [:a :b :c] 5)
  nil
```

2) Consistency in form with other Clojure functions

```
> (get {:a "b"} :a)
  :b
> (contains? {:a "b"} :a)
  true
> (nth [:a :b :c] 1)
  :b
> (conj [:a :b] :c)
  [:a :b :c]
```

3) Alignment benefits of map-first

```
> (my-func
    (get my-map :un)
    (get my-map :deux)
    (get my-map :trois)
    (get my-map :quatre)
    (get my-map :cinq))
```

4) Get-in can be used for nested access with a single call

```
> (get-in my-map [:alpha  :beta  :gamma  :delta])
> (aget   js-obj  "alpha" "beta" "gamma" "delta")
```

Source: testing on http://tryclj.com/

Comment: FYI - "default can be provided if no value is found" is also true when using a keyword as a function

ie: `(:foo {:bar "baz} 4)` returns `4`

Comment: @ChrisOakman You're right.  Providing a default is available to all forms of access, so I removed that from the list.

Answer (score 0):

I would say either is idiomatic. The only caveat is that the second form only works with keywords. Which, I assume by being a deliberate design choice, would give it more reason to be idiomatic.

Comment: It works on symbols too, and anything else that happens to implement IFn by looking itself up in an Associative. `(let [k 'key-sym, m {k 1}] (k m)) ;=> 1`. And similarly, the `(m k)` form doesn't work on records, because they don't implement IFn (for good reason, even if it is inconvenient).