# clojure: calling a static method of a java class with variable args

Tags: java, image, clojure

I am trying to use the [Scalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) java image resizing library from clojure:

```
[org.imgscalr/imgscalr-lib "4.2"]
```

When I import it and try to use it it fails, because of the variable number of args each method takes:

```
(import 'org.imgscalr.Scalr)
(def image (*acquire BufferedImage instance*))
(Scalr/resize image 200)
```

This gives me this error:

```
No matching method: resize
```

This is because (as I have figured out) resize takes as its last argument a variable number of BufferedImageOps.  So, I try to pass in a java array for these:

```
(import 'java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp)
(Scalr/resize image 200 (into-array BufferedImageOp []))
```

But this fails with

```
No message.
[Thrown class java.lang.ClassCastException]
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you are not acquiring the image as expected. 
e.g. This works for me....

```
*clojure-version*
{:major 1, :minor 3, :incremental 0, :qualifier nil}
user> (import 'java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp)
java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp
user> (import 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
java.awt.image.BufferedImage
user> (Scalr/resize (BufferedImage. 10 10 BufferedImage/TYPE_INT_ARGB) 200 (into-array BufferedImageOp []))
#<BufferedImage BufferedImage@ccfe446: type = 2 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=ff000000 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 200 height = 200 #Bands = 4 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0>
user>
```

Comment: Thank you!  The image was being returned in a map, I had to go (image :image).  My bad.

Comment: No problem. You should note that for maps ``(:keyword map)`` is idiomatic rather than ``(map :keyword)``. Discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034803/idiomatic-clojure-map-lookup-by-keyword

Answer (score 0):

The `into-array` call looks okay, but the method signature found [**here**](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/Scalr.html#resize%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20int,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp...%29) takes a java.lang.Integer, and in Clojure your `200` will be a java.lang.Long by default.

How about casting to an int:

```
(Scalr/resize image (int 200) (into-array BufferedImageOp []))
```