# what advantage is there to use 'get' instead to access a map

Tags: clojure

Following up from this question: [Idiomatic clojure map lookup by keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034803/idiomatic-clojure-map-lookup-by-keyword)

Map access using clojure can be done in many ways.

```
(def m {:a 1}

(get m :a) ;; => 1
(:a m) ;; => 1
(m :a) ;; => 1
```

I know I use mainly the second form, and sometimes the third, rarely the first. what are the advantages (speed/composability) of using each?

Comment: See answers in the question you linked. The only other thing that comes to mind for get is the 3-arity version (get map key not-found) where you get (pun intended) to specify a default.

Comment: @A.Webb You can specify a default for all three uses: `(:k m default)` and `(m :k default)` both work, provided m is not nil of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the clojure web page](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Maps%20%28IPersistentMap%29) we see that

> Maps implement IFn, for invoke() of one argument (a key) with an
>   optional second argument (a default value), i.e. maps are functions of
>   their keys. nil keys and values are ok.

Sometimes it is rewarding to take a look under the hoods of Clojure. If you look up what `invoke` looks like in a map, you see this:

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/APersistentMap.java#L196

It apparently calls the `valAt` method of a map.

If you look at what the `get` function does when called with a map, this is a call to `clojure.lang.RT.get`, and this really boils down to the same call to `valAt` for a map (maps implement ILookUp because they are [Associatives](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Associative.java)):

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L634.

The same is true for a map called with a key and a not-found-value. So, what is the advantage? Since both ways boil down to pretty much the same, performance wise I would say nothing. It's just syntactic convenience.

Answer (score 13):

`get` is useful when the map could be nil or not-a-map, and the key could be something non-callable (i.e. not a keyword)

```
(def m nil)
(def k "some-key")

(m k)  =>  NullPointerException
(k m)  =>  ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

(get m k)  =>  nil
(get m :foo :default)  =>  :default
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `get` to `partial` etc. to build up HOFs for messing with your data, though it doesn't come up often.

```
user=> (def data {"a" 1 :b 2})
#'user/data
user=> (map (partial get data) (keys data))
(1 2)
```

I use the third form a lot when the data has strings as keys

Comment: That doesn't really address the question. You could just as easily `(map data (keys data))` to get an equivalent of `(vals data)`.

Comment: The point is that get can be composed with function transforming functions to produce a data-twiddling function before the data map is available. This example illustrates that point in isolation though in practice it comes up combined with other problem-specific constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a speed difference, and even if that would be the case, that would be an implementation detail.

Personally I prefer the second option (:a m) because it sometimes makes code a bit easier on the eye. For example, I often have to iterate through a sequence of maps:

```
(def foo '({:a 1} {:a 2} {:a 3}))
```

If I want to filter all values of :a I can now use:

```
(map :a foo)
```

Instead of

```
(map #(get % :a) foo)
```

or

```
(map #(% :a) foo)
```

Of course this is a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the list, get is also useful when using the threading macro `->` and you need to access via a key that is not a keyword

`(let [m {"a" :a}]
  (-> m
      (get "a")))`

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of using the keyword first approach is it is the most concise way of accessing the value with a forgiving behavior in the case the map is nil.