# What is the difference between calling a hash-map against symbol versus calling a symbol against a hash-map?

Tags: clojure, hashmap, expression

Hash map is a function in Clojure and it returns the value by the key which is provided as its first parameter. Say,

```
({:zero 0 :one 1} :zero)
;;=> 0
```

But it also works other way around:

```
(:zero {:zero 0 :one 1})
;;=> 0
```

What's the difference? Are there any cases when the two return different things? What is the conventional way? What is most industry recognized way (most widespread among those who create production-ready Clojure code)?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915531/why-does-using-keywords-or-symbols-as-functions-to-lookup-values-from-maps-work 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034803/idiomatic-clojure-map-lookup-by-keyword http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281631/what-do-clojure-symbols-do-when-used-as-functions/12281633#12281633 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488788/what-advantage-is-there-to-use-get-instead-to-access-a-map

Comment: ...and even a [style guide entry](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#keywords-as-fn-to-get-map-values).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14490117/1287643) is what I've been searching for. Thanks for references.