# ClojureScript - store functions in map

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, idioms

I am using a map to store function calls (in ClojureScript, but it should be the same in Clojure) :

```
(def parse-fn {:json    js/JSON.parse
               :edn     read-string
               :transit t->clj})
```

I then have a `transform` function like the following :

```
(defn transform [format data]
  ((get parse-fn format) data))
```

Calling `transform` like that : `(transform :transit data)` works nicely. I am only worried about the readability of the `transform` function. It is not immediately obvious that the first thing is a function.

*Edit :* I cannot just call `(:transit parse-fn)` since the `format` comes from another function, as in : `(another-fn [... format ...] ... (transform format data))`

Is there an explicit `call` function, or is the structure of this code not idiomatic ?

Comment: i find it actually quite readable.  "get me the parse function for transit, then call it with data".  double `((` are not that common, so a reader would actually take a moment here.

Comment: Consider using [multimethods](http://clojure.org/multimethods) to dispatch on the keyword instead of a map storing functions to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial design is completely readable. Passing functions to other functions that do the actual work is a fairly normal way of doing things. I don't think you need to change anything to "make it more readable". If i was going to change anything to make i more clrearly spelled out would be to change the name of transform to transform-lookup or get-transform

```
(another-fn [... format ...] ... (transform-lookup format data))
```

or

```
(another-fn [... format ...] ... (get-transform format data))
```

Though this is a very minor distinction and it's fine the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider treating the keyword as the function.

```
((:transit parse-fn) data)
```

To me the more terse approach helps me recognise the first element as distinct.

Alternatively, you can treat the map as the function instead.

```
((parse-fn :transit) data)
```

As I understand, the first approach is generally considered more idiomatic and it can also [be optimized more intelligently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7035984/1088797).

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't completely clear, I'll edit it.

Comment: Then replace transit with format? I might have misunderstood the intention here.

Comment: Still not sure I understand, I thought the problem was with readability? So it works nicely like this `(transform :transit data)`. It shouldn't matter where the format comes from, so long as it is a symbol, you should be able to use it just the same as the above approach just like `(transform format data)`?