# Clojure: Is using a hash as a function ok?

Tags: clojure, hashmap

These both work:

```
=> (def hash {:a "potato" :b "pants"})
#'hash
=> (hash :a)
"potato"
=> (:a hash)
"potato"
```

Is there any reason I should prefer one of these over the other?  I see more people doing the latter `(:a hash)`... why?  I like the former `(hash :a)` because it resembles the structure of `(-> hash :a :b :c)`, which I prefer to the noisier `(get-in hash [:a :b :c])`.

Is there some efficiency difference or something between these?

Comment: Hash first is also consistent with `([:a :b :c] 2)` which does not work the other way around.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034803/idiomatic-clojure-map-lookup-by-keyword

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `(:key hash)` when you have static keyword key and dynamic map. 
Use `({:a 1 :b 2} k)` when you have static map and dynamic key.
Use `(get hash key)` when map and key both dynamic. This shows why

```
> (def hm nil)
> (def knil nil)
> (def kother 1)

> (hm :key)
NullPointerException ...
> (:key hm)
nil

> (kother {:a 1})
ClassCastException
> (knil {:a 1})
NullPointerException
> ({:a 1} kother)
nil

> (get hm knil)
nil
> (get hm kother)
nil
```

Or you can use `get` everywhere and don't bother yourself for this. But it's longer to type and code can get messy with brackets. This looks reasonable to use `(hm key)` if you sure that `cipher` is not `nil`

```
> (def message "hello")
> (let [cipher {\h \1 \e \f \l \# \o \p}]  
    (apply str (map cipher message)))
"1f##p"
```

Answer (score 1):

The link given by @leeor is quite comprehensive. I'll just add a little bit more experiment here:

```
user> (time (let [m {:a :b}] (dotimes [i 900000000] (m :a))))
"Elapsed time: 4609.565862 msecs"
=> nil
user> (time (let [m {:a :b}] (dotimes [i 900000000] (get m :a))))
"Elapsed time: 9556.065868 msecs"
=> nil
user> (time (let [m {:a :b}] (dotimes [i 900000000] (:a m))))
"Elapsed time: 11220.804791 msecs"
=> nil
```

This result kind of contradicts with @amalloy's argument on hotspot optimization. Maybe it's because REPL interpretation is not hotspot optimized?