# What's difference between object-like-map and collection-like-map in clojure?

Tags: clojure

According to [Clojure's code standards](https://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards), there is a convention on which should go first, key or map, when selecting an element from a map. But the standards make a distinction based on whether the map is a "object-like-map" or a "collection-like-map".

> Use keyword-first syntax to access properties on objects: (:property
>   object-like-map)
>
> Use collection-first syntax to extract values from a collection (or
>   use get if the collection might be nil). (collection-like-map key)
>   (get collection-like-map key)

How would one define "object-like-map" and "collection-like-map", and how are they different?

Comment: The Learn Clojure guide also talks about those two distinct uses of maps: https://clojure.org/guides/learn/hashed_colls#_maps

Comment: Same question asked from a different angle: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7034803

Answer (score 2):

I would say that an object-like map is an encapsulation of state or a higher-level data type where the name, number, and types of fields are determined in advance.

```
(def rectangle {:length 7, :width 12, :color "#0000FF"})
```

In that case it's very natural to access by the keyword `(:length rectangle)`.

My idea of collection-type maps is that they tend to be homogeneous collections where you don't know the number nor exactly which keys will be present. Imagine a map counting occurrences of genres in a music collection (`{:kpop 19, :smooth-jazz 7, :classic-rock 134, ...}`)

```
(def genre-count (count-genres "/data/my-song-list"))
```

Then, according to the style guide at least, it's natural to get the count of words with

```
(genre-count :punk)
```

more than `(:punk genre-count)`,

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that a collection like map is a collection of keys and values in which the keys are not necessarily keywords and therefore, using the key as a function in order to extract the value will not do:

```
(:keyword my-map)
```

In that case use `get`:

```
(get my-map keyword)
```

an object like map, like a record has keys and values that represent properties and keywords are used exclusively.